# How to avoid stacking navigation history in tab-bar states

Tags: angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

Tab A - Tab B - Tab C

States like below;
tabs.a, tabs.b, tab.c

I want to close app like there is no navigation history when switching in each of tab states

For example: I was in Tab A then I clicked to Tab B and then I clicked to Tab C from now on if user pushes back button the app should close. In normal behaviour navigation history stacks up and if I push back button I'll go to Tab B from Tab C. How to avoid this behaviour

Below is my codes;

```js
.state('tabs', {
                url: "/tab",
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
            })
            .state('tabs.a', {
                url: "/a",
                views: {
                    'a-tab': {
                        templateUrl: "templates/a.html",
                        controller: 'AController'
                    }
                }
            }).state('tabs.b', {
                url: "/b",
                views: {
                    'b-tab': {
                        templateUrl: "templates/b.html",
                        controller: 'BController'
                    }
                }
            }).state('tabs.c', {
                url: "/c",
                views: {
                    'c-tab': {
                        templateUrl: "templates/c.html",
                        controller: 'CController'
                    }
                }
            });
```

```html
<ion-tabs class="tabs-royal tabs-striped">
    <ion-tab title="A" href="#/tab/a">
        <ion-nav-view name="a-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="B" href="#/tab/b">
        <ion-nav-view name="b-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="C" href="#/tab/c">
        <ion-nav-view name="b-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it with a simple way
Added a function in controller scope of tabs state

```js
.state('tabs', {
                url: "/tab",
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html",
                controller: function($scope, $ionicTabsDelegate, $ionicHistory) {
                    $scope.rt = function(e, index) {
                        $ionicTabsDelegate.select(index);
                        //e.preventDefault();
                        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({historyRoot:true});
                    }
                }
            })
```

and added ng-click on each ion-tab directive in tabs.html template like below;

```html
<ion-tab ng-click="rt($event, 0)" title="A" href="#/tab/a">
```

The second parameter of rt function is the index of tab

I used $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({historyRoot:true});

From the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/)

> **nextViewOptions()**
>   Sets options for the next view. This method can be
>   useful to override certain view/transition defaults right before a
>   view transition happens. For example, the menuClose directive uses
>   this method internally to ensure an animated view transition does not
>   happen when a side menu is open, and also sets the next view as the
>   root of its history stack. After the transition these options are set
>   back to null.
>
> Available options:
>
> **disableAnimate:** Do not animate the next transition.
>   **disableBack:** The next view should forget its back view, and set it to null.
>   **historyRoot:** The next view should become the root view in its history stack.

That way I achieved what I want

Comment: it closes the app i've tested on android device. Have you tested and didnt get it working ?

Comment: You should use `ionic.Platform.exitApp()` to be sure your app closes.

Comment: If you're on root of the history it will always close the app. Its default behaviour of cordova and even ionic imo

Answer (score 2):

You can intercept the back button in each of your controllers.
From the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/):

> **registerBackButtonAction(callback, priority, [actionId])** Register a
>   hardware back button action. Only one action will execute when the
>   back button is clicked, so this method decides which of the registered
>   back button actions has the highest priority.
>
> For example, if an actionsheet is showing, the back button should
>   close the actionsheet, but it should not also go back a page view or
>   close a modal which may be open.
>
> The priorities for the existing back button hooks are as follows:
>   Return to previous view = 100 Close side menu = 150 Dismiss modal =
>   200 Close action sheet = 300 Dismiss popup = 400 Dismiss loading
>   overlay = 500
>
> Your back button action will override each of the above actions whose
>   priority is less than the priority you provide. For example, an action
>   assigned a priority of 101 will override the 'return to previous view'
>   action, but not any of the other actions.

In your controllers you can register a listener for the back button and exit if it has been pressed:

```
.controller('AController', function($scope, $ionicPlatform){
    var deregister = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(
            function () {
                ionic.Platform.exitApp();
            }, 100
    );
    $scope.$on('$destroy', deregister)    
})    

.controller('BController', function($scope, $ionicPlatform){
    var deregister = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(
            function () {
                ionic.Platform.exitApp();
            }, 100
    );
    $scope.$on('$destroy', deregister)    


})

.controller('CController', function($scope, $ionicPlatform){
  var deregister = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(
            function () {
                ionic.Platform.exitApp();
            }, 100
    );
    $scope.$on('$destroy', deregister)    

});
```

**NOTES**:

Your last tab (C TAB) should have the name: `c-tab`:

```
<ion-tab title="C" href="#/tab/c">
    <ion-nav-view name="c-tab"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying and the notes. They are sample code. My actual html and javascript codes are valid thank you